# How do you fit a Carousel inside a container alongside another block, while keeping the height of both containers the same?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, row, carousel

I have a `row` of Bootstrap columns `col-sm-4` and `col-sm-8`. In `col-sm-4` there is just text information. In `col-sm-8` there is a Carousel with images as you can see [here](http://te-al.co.uk/home#about).

I am trying to fit my Carousel inside the column (`col-sm-8`) so that when the page is resized the Carousel will not shrink below the height of the column/row.

My question isn't a duplicate as my columns aren't a fixed height, if I add more text to the left column it will increase in size and the right will match its height because of .div-equalheightfix in my CSS, however the Carousel inside that div shrinks too small when below a certain size.

These images illustrate what I mean:

**Current**

[image: My problem currently.]

**Desired**

[image: The result I am aiming for.]

And here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%;background-color:#252525;">
  <div class="row" style="display:table;">
    <!-- text column (left) -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 div-equalheightfix div-aboutus">
      <p>Text goes here.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- carousel column (right) -->
    <div class="col-sm-8 hidden-xs div-equalheightfix">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- indicators/buttons -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- images -->
        <div class="carousel-inner clickthrough" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/fader/img001.jpg" class="carousel-img" data-no-retina>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="images/fader/img002.jpg" class="carousel-img" data-no-retina>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* ensures that both columns are always equal height */
.div-equalheightfix {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* carousel css */
.carousel.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: auto -15px auto -15px;
}
.carousel.fade .item {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  position: absolute;
  display: block !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel.fade .item:first-child {
  top: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel.fade .item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -o-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .7s;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* text-column CSS */
.div-aboutus {
  padding: 2% 8% 6% 4%;
  color: #F1F1F2;
  line-height: 175%;
}
.carousel-img {

}
```

update: I can change the image height by adjusting the img element, however I have added a class for this `.carousel-img`. I'm not sure what to add in there to make the height automatically go inline with the height of the text column, `min-height:100%;` makes it the same height as the browser window and not the container. Any suggestions?

update #2: see my answer below for an alternative solution, it seems better to do this without using Bootstrap columns; I have edited the title to match.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I used an overlay over the top of the Carousel `div` using CSS `z-index`. You can see the result [here](http://www.te-al.co.uk/home#about).

It is an alternative rather than a solution, however I'm sure something could be achieved much easier without using Bootstrap columns at all; perhaps using [`clearfix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix).